# Nova setup error (MissingAuthPlugin)

Tags: openstack-nova, nova-network, nova

so when i was following Openstack Yoga installation i got error adding nova-conductor and nova-scheduler.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5e6A.png) when i read conductor's log, it said

CRITICAL nova [-] Unhandled error: keystoneauth1.exceptions.auth_plugins.MissingAuthPlugin: An auth plugin is required to determine endpoint URL

i don't know how to fix this, please help me
thanks

edit: after reading conductor and scheduler's log, i've found another error:

amqp.exceptions.AccessRefused: (0, 0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the solution for this ? I was facing the same `missing auth_plugin` error in `nova-conductor.log`. I am a noob myself. Nova-conductor and scheduler services weren't starting. I am installing `Antelope` on Ubuntu 22.04.

Error

```
2023-11-09 16:38:53.004 39172 ERROR nova.conductor.manager [-] Fatal error initializing placement client; config is incorrect or incomplete: An auth plugin is required to determine endpoint URL: keystoneauth1.exceptions.auth_plugins.MissingAuthPlugin: An auth plugin is required to determine endpoint URL
2023-11-09 16:38:53.004 39172 CRITICAL nova [-] Unhandled error: keystoneauth1.exceptions.auth_plugins.MissingAuthPlugin: An auth plugin is required to determine endpoint URL
```

https://docs.openstack.org/nova/2023.2/install/controller-install-rdo.html,
As per this link, I put the placement section in the `nova-api.conf` file and that fixed it.

```
systemctl -l | grep nova
  nova-api.service                                                                          loaded active running   OpenStack Compute API
  nova-conductor.service                                                                    loaded active running   OpenStack Compute Conductor
  nova-novncproxy.service                                                                   loaded active running   OpenStack Compute novncproxy
  nova-scheduler.service                                                                    loaded active running   OpenStack Compute Scheduler
```

I can query the compute api with `openstack compute service list`

Hope this helps.

Best,
J